# Why ElasticSearch is not able to search when special characters are available?

Tags: tokenize, elasticsearch-5, analyzer

I have an ElasticSearch index with below configuration:

```
{
  "my_ind": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "mapping": {
          "total_fields": {
            "limit": "10000000"
          }
        },
        "number_of_shards": "3",
        "provided_name": "my_ind",
        "creation_date": "1539773409246",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "default": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "3wC7i-E_Q9mSDjnTN2gxrg",
        "version": {
          "created": "5061299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to search below content with plain search:

```
DL-1234170386456
```

This contents are available in the below field:

```
DNumber
```

This filed has mapping like below:

```
{
  "DNumber": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement it in JAVA language. I came across the ElasticSearch Analyzers and Tokenizers so I made use of "**whitespace**" tokenizer.

I am trying to search with below query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "DL-1234170386456",
      "fields": [
        "_all"
      ],
      "type": "best_fields",
      "operator": "OR",
      "analyzer": "default",
      "slop": 0,
      "prefix_length": 0,
      "max_expansions": 50,
      "lenient": false,
      "zero_terms_query": "NONE",
      "boost": 1
    }
  }
}
```

What wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

After doing lot of research and Trial & Error, found out the answer!

**Some basic but important points:**

- We need to specify Analyzers and Tokenizers while creating/indexing the index/data.
- In specified string i.e. "DL-1234170386456", special character (i.e. "-") is available and ElasticSearch is using by default [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).
- Standard Analyzer contains [Standard Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-tokenizer.html) which is based on the Unicode Text Segmentation algorithm.

**Actual Problem:**

ElasticSearch is separating the String ("DL-1234170386456") into two different parts like "DL" and "1234170386456".

**Solution:**

- We need to specify [Whitespace Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-analyzer.html) which contains [Whitespace Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html).
- It will split the word whenever space is encountered. So, String ("DL-1234170386456") will kept as it is by ElasticSearch and we are able to find it out.